# Writing list with elements of different classes into a text file

Tags: r

How to write a list of different class variables into a text file consequently using `R` base functions?

`write` and `cat` can't handle data.frames and `write.table` is specific to tables only. None of them handles lists properly.
Sample list:

```
> test
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "e" "f"

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
  X.g. X.h. X.i.
1    g    h    i

[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "k"

[[5]][[2]]
[1] "l"

[[5]][[3]]
[1] "m" "n"


[[6]]
[1] "2015-03-23 11:15:00 CET"
```

It consists of `character`, `numeric`, `POSIXlt`time variable and another list.

Desired result - a text file like that:

```
a b c
d e f
1 2 3
X.g.    X.h.    X.i.
1   g   h   i
k
l
m n
2015-03-23 11:15:00
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a script to handle lists by class of elements and print it into file one by one:

```
write_list <- function (outlist, outfile,append=FALSE) {
    for (i in 1:length(outlist)) {
      if (i==1) app=append else app=TRUE
      if (is.character(outlist[[i]]) || is.numeric(outlist[[i]])) write(paste(outlist[[i]],collapse = " "),outfile, append=app)
      else 
        if (is.data.frame(outlist[[i]])) write.table(outlist[[i]],outfile, append=app, quote=FALSE, sep="\t")
        else 
          if (is.POSIXlt(outlist[[i]])) write (as.character(outlist[[i]]),outfile, append=app)
          else
            if  (is.list(outlist[[i]])) write_list(outlist = outlist[[i]], outfile, append = TRUE)

    }
}
```

`is.POSIXlt` is a custom function:

```
is.POSIXlt <- function (ts) {
isPOS=c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")

identical (class(ts),isPOS)
}
```

The final `if` statement is a recursive call - a case for 'list of lists' situation. It calls itself for inner list and handles it by element.